# Has the notion of "non-cheating" quines been formalised?

Tags: formal-languages

Informally, it is often said that some [quines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) "cheat", such as those that read their own source code from memory, or the case where a program consisting of the empty string happens to output the empty string.

Quines that are considerd to be "non-cheating" always seem to have the same structure. There is some data structure (usually, but not always, a string) which contains some representation of the source code. This structure is read twice, once to reformat it into the code part of the final output, and a second time where it's copied verbatim to reproduce the data part. For example, the following Python example (which I just invented) has this structure:

```
x = """x = {0}{1}{0}
print x.format(chr(34)*3,x)"""
print x.format(chr(34)*3,x)
```

The string 'x' is referred to twice in the last line, once to reformat it, and a second time to paste it verbatim into the reformatted string.

My question is whether this notion of "cheating" or "non-cheating" quines has been, or can be, formalised. That is to say, if we are given a formal specification of a language and its semantics, and we are also given an example of a quine in that language, is there a well-defined way to say, in principle, whether that quine is "cheating" or not? Or is this notion of "cheating" inherently too vague to admit a formal definition?

If this notion can be formally defined, is it possible to have a language that only admits "non-cheating" quines, and is an example of such a language known?

Comment: I wonder if a [tag:quines] tag would be useful? If it would, could someone with the necessary rep create it and apply it to my question?

Answer (score 2):

Most formal semantics for programing languages tend to keep things simple, in particular, it's pretty rare to have the ability to express "grabbing your own source code" in a formal semantics.

This has the somewhat dubious advantage of disallowing some kinds of "cheating" *by construction*: the "cheat" is simply not part of the language semantics. In particular, a simple lambda calculus with simple string concatenation and printing primitives cannot implement many (any?) of the "cheats" you have in mind. In such a language, a quine might be a program which prints the exact string representation of it's own code. You can even avoid the `print` primitive if you allow returning the string rather than printing it. In that case, you only need string literals and concatenation.

It's a useful exercise to figure out various properties of quines in such a language. It's pretty easy to see that some variable will need to be repeated twice: there are no "linear" quines. However the statement

> This structure is read twice, once to reformat it into the code part of the final output, and a second time where it's copied verbatim to reproduce the data part.

is a bit vague, and I'm not sure it's true in general, depending on the precise meaning of "copied verbatim".

Comment: I can think of several ways that "cheating" could exist in such a language. In particular, depending on the details of the formalism, I would expect the empty string to output the empty string.

Comment: I'm aware that the concept I'm getting at is vague, but then, if it were precise I would have no need to ask a question about how to formalise it. To my mind, my second question (can we define a language with no cheating quines?) can only be answered after my first question (can we turn this vague concept of 'cheating' into a formal one?).

Comment: I think you can exclude the first case by definition: a quine needs to be a *function definition* $q:\mathrm{String}\rightarrow\mathrm{String}$ that prints it's own code. This prevents the "empty" loophole. For the "reads it's own code" loophole, I think this simply isn't possible in the simple language I outlined. Of course, other forms of cheating might exist (depending on the judge), but I feel this excludes the ones mentioned at least.